# Может ли "в действительности" быть вводным выражением?

Tags: пунктуация

Может ли "в действительности" быть вводным выражением, или это всегда обстоятельство?

Answer (score 3):

> Может ли “в действительности” быть вводным выражением?

В *"Словаре вводных слов"* Остроумовой и Фрамполь о ***в действительности*** говорится так:

> Редко обособляется при желании автора придать обстоятельству ***в
>   действительности*** особую значимость, интонационно выделяется:
>
> *Оторвана ли от истории, **в действительности**, тяга людей к братской солидарности и душевной чуткости?* (А. Платонов);
>
> *В целом книги, **в действительности**, не столь конечны, как мы сами* (И. Бродский).
>
> **Потенциально вводное.**

См.:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Падежная форма "в действительности" может быть и вводным словом, и обстоятельством.

**1. Вводное слово "в действительности"**

Вводные слова - это не содержание сообщения, а отношение говорящего к этому сообщению. Тематика вводных слов - это (1) отношение к действительности (реальное, возможное, сомнительное и др), (2) выражение чувств, (3) оформление речи. В каждой теме  можно выделить синонимичные группы вводных слов, заменяющих друг друга. Вводные слова не связаны с другими членами предложения грамматической связью и всегда обособляются.

Пример: Что еще, на самом деле (= собственно говоря, = в действительности) человеку надо? Итак, самый простой пример: Что еще, **в действительности**,  человеку надо? **Это не авторское обособление обстоятельство, а вводное слово.**

**2. Обстоятельство "в действительности"**

Обстоятельство - это член предложения,  грамматически связанный с другими словами. Обстоятельство также можно заменить синонимом, например: Но что **в действительности** (= по-настоящему) волнует простых людей? (Обычно обстоятельство не обособляется, но может быть обособлено, если структура предложения способствует этому).

**3. Парные варианты:**

**Обстоятельство** (выделяется ударением): В целом книги **в действИтельности** (= и правда) не столь конечны, как мы сами.

**Вводное слово (вставочная интонация):** В целом книги, **в действительности** ( по мнению многих, как уже не раз говорилось), не столь конечны, как мы сами.